# How can I call a callback functions with parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm currently using the [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) to make a simple search with Wikipedia, I have a `<select>` dropdown and a simple input with an autocomplete.

What I'm trying to do is to be able to search in different languages, the auto-complete works fine with languages but when I'm trying to search by clicking on one of my auto-complete links it returns "undefined". (e.g. `undefined.wikipedia.org` instead of `en.wikipedia.org`)

Here's what I tried so far:

```js
// Function to select id
var yb = {
  id: function(str) {
    return document.getElementById(str);
  },
};

var tag = "";

// When user is typing
yb.id("search").onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (!e.keyCode.toString().match(/^(37|38|39|40|13|16|17|18|224)$/)) {
    if (tag !== "") {
      document.body.removeChild(tag);
    }

    tag = document.createElement("script");
    var term = yb.id("search").value;
    var lang = yb.id("lang").value;

    // API link
    tag.src =
      "https://" + lang + ".wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=10&format=json&callback=ybComplete&search=" +
      term;
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  }
};

// The search function
function ybComplete(data, lang) {
  yb.id("wikiOutput").innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (data[1][i]) {
      yb.id("wikiOutput").innerHTML +=
        '<p><b><a href="https://' + lang + '.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
        data[1][i] +
        '">' +
        data[1][i] +
        "</a></b><br>" +
        data[2][i] +
        "</p>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
<select id="lang" name="lang">
  <option value="en" selected="selected">Language</option>
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>

<div id="wikiOutput"></div>
```

In the API link there is a parameter "callback" which calls my function (`ybComplete()`), how can I tell the link to be able to change the language based on the `lang` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass the lang. Get it from the select

here is a better version that redoes the search when you change the language

```js
// Function to select id
var yb = {
  id: function(str) {
    return document.getElementById(str);
  },
};

let keyupEvent = new Event('keyup');
let wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=10&format=json&callback=ybComplete&search="
let tag = "";

// When user is typing
yb.id("search").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (!e.keyCode || !e.keyCode.toString().match(/^(37|38|39|40|13|16|17|18|224)$/)) {
    if (tag !== "") {
      document.body.removeChild(tag);
    }

    tag = document.createElement("script");
    const term = yb.id("search").value;
    // API link
    tag.src = wiki + encodeURIComponent(term);
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  }
});

yb.id("lang").addEventListener("change", function() {
  wiki = wiki.replace(/[a-z]{2}\.wikipedia\.org/,this.value+".wikipedia.org")
  yb.id("search").dispatchEvent(keyupEvent)
})

// The search function
function ybComplete(data) {
  yb.id("wikiOutput").innerHTML = "";
  const lang = yb.id("lang").value
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (data[1][i]) {
      yb.id("wikiOutput").innerHTML +=
        '<p><b><a href="https://' + lang + '.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
        data[1][i] +
        '">' +
        data[1][i] +
        "</a></b><br>" +
        data[2][i] +
        "</p>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
<select id="lang" name="lang">
  <option value="en" selected="selected">Language</option>
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>

<div id="wikiOutput"></div>
```

Comment: @MichaelBurns I rewrote to handle a change of language while still text in the input field

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.
Instead of using ybComplete as a callback use this function:

```
beforeYbComplete(data){
   ybComplete(yb.id("lang").value, data)
}
```

And change this line in handleSearch:

```
// API link
tag.src = "https://" + lang + ".wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=10&format=json&callback=beforeYbComplete&search=" + term;
```